# Prove that $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ/3))$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ))$ and compute its degree $[\mathbb Q(\sin(θ/3)):\mathbb Q(\sin(θ))]$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> **Problem:** Prove that $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ/3))$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ))$ and compute its degree $[\mathbb Q(\sin(θ/3)):\mathbb Q(\sin(θ))]$ in terms of $θ ∈ \mathbb R$.

I can prove that it is a field extension, because $\sin(θ) = 3\sin(θ/3)-4\sin^3(θ/3)$. I can't really prove that it is finite, or what the basis should be for $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ/3))$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(\sin(θ))$.
We define $F(S)$ as the smallest field containing $F$ and $S$, or as $\operatorname{Frac}(F[S])$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1):

You found a polynomial equation of degree $3$ for $\sin(\theta/3)$ over the field $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta)$, so why don't you see that $\sin(\theta/3)$ is algebraic over $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta)$?

Note that the field degree will depend on $\theta$.

If $\theta = 0$, then $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta)$ and $\mathbf Q(\sin(\theta/3))$ are both just $\mathbf Q$.

If $\theta = \pi$ then $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta) = \mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf Q(\sin(\pi/3)) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3}/2) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$, which has degree $2$ over $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta)$.

If $\theta = \pi/6$, then $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta) = \mathbf Q$ and $1/2 = \sin(\theta) = 3\sin(\theta/3) - 4\sin^3(\theta/3)$, so $\sin(\theta/3)$ is a root of $4x^3 - 3x + 1/2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ (it's irreducible mod $5$), so $\mathbf Q(\sin(\theta/3))$ has degree $3$ over $\mathbf Q(\sin\theta)$.

Comment: What do you mean with algebraïc over Q(sin(θ))?

Comment: I know that the degree will change depending on the value of theta, but how can we classify this for all values of theta? I tried splitting into cases for values of sin(θ), but never seem to get a full answer. e.g. what if sin(θ)=pi/10?

Comment: Saying a number is algebraic over a field just means it's the root of a nonconstant polynomial with coefficients in that field. Look up the term "algebraic" in your algebra book or google it in the setting of field theory. Any book discussing field extensions will have the term "algebraic" in it.

Comment: If $t = \sin(\theta)$ is $\pi/10$ then $t$ is transcendental, so $\sin(\theta/3)$ is a root of $4x^3 - 3x + t \in \mathbf Q(t)[x] = \mathbf Q(\pi)[x]$.  If you have experience working with transcendental field extensions then figure out if that cubic is irreducible or not over $\mathbf Q(t)$, but if you don't have experience with such fields then the question is beyond your current abilities and you'll need to learn about transcendental extensions.  Is this a course exercise or some random problem you're trying to answer?

Comment: The ring $\mathbf Q[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ is the *same* as the field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ since $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are algebraic over $\mathbf Q$. If $F$ is a field and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ then the ring $F[\alpha]$ (polynomial expressions in $\alpha$ with $F$-coefficients) is a field, so $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ (rational expressions in $\alpha$ with $F$-coefficients). But if $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$ then $F[\alpha]$ is not a field and it's smaller than $F(\alpha)$. For example, $\mathbf Q[\pi] \not= \mathbf Q(\pi)$. Sounds like you have more sloppy exercises.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your reply, thank you a lot though. The problem is, what should I write then?

Comment: That is something you'll need to ask your professor.  We can't read his mind about his intentions since to me his question sounds ambiguous.